# Keycloak gives invalid username & password error on admin console despite docker-compose configuration

Tags: docker, docker-compose, keycloak

I have leveraged **Keycloak** in **production mode** behind nginx via **docker-compose** file in my Centos 8 machine. TLS is set in load balancer, not in the machine. But when I try to access admin console in browser with the credentials I provide **(KEYCLOAK_ADMIN and KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD)** in docker-compose file, it gives ***"Invalid username or password."*** error.

**docker-compose.yaml file:**

```
nginx:
build: ./nginx/.
container_name: nginx
ports:
  - "8443:80"
depends_on:
  - keycloak
networks:
  - keycloak_nginx_network

keycloak:
image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:23.0.4
container_name: keycloak
command: start
restart: always
ports:
  - "8080:8080" 
environment:
  KC_DB: postgres
  KC_DB_URL_HOST: postgres
  KC_DB_URL_DATABASE: keycloak
  KC_DB_PASSWORD: password
  KC_DB_USERNAME: postgres_user
  KC_DB_SCHEMA: public
  KC_PROXY: edge
  KEYCLOAK_ADMIN: admin
  KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD: admin
  KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT_HTTPS: "true"
  KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT_BACKCHANNEL: "true"
  KEYCLOAK_FRONTEND_URL: "some-url/auth"
  KC_HOSTNAME_URL: some-url
  KC_HOSTNAME_ADMIN_URL: some-url
depends_on:
  postgres_keycloak:
    condition: service_healthy
networks:
  - keycloak_nginx_network
```

**nginx.conf:**

```
events {}
http {
server {
location / {
 proxy_http_version 1.1;
 proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
 proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
 proxy_set_header Host $host;
 proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
 proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
 proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
 proxy_set_header content-type "application/json";

 proxy_buffer_size 128k;
 proxy_buffers 4 256k;
 proxy_busy_buffers_size 256k;
    
 proxy_pass http://keycloak:8080;
 proxy_read_timeout 300s;
 proxy_connect_timeout 300s;
 proxy_send_timeout 300s;   
}
}
}
```

When I enter username: admin & password: admin in browser, The error definition I get in docker logs:

```
WARN  [org.keycloak.events] (executor-thread-1) type=LOGIN_ERROR, realmId=some-realm-id, clientId=security-admin-console, userId=null, ipAddress=some-ip, error=user_not_found, auth_method=openid-connect, auth_type=code, redirect_uri=some-uri, code_id=some-code-id
```

1 row above this warning, it says:

```
INFO  [org.keycloak.services] (main) KC-SERVICES0009: Added user 'some-user' to realm 'master'
```

I assume it is HTTPS related problem. Because when I give http links to KC_HOSTNAME_URL and KC_HOSTNAME_ADMIN_URL, it successfully signs in to the admin console.

Obviously I have already provided credentials but it keeps giving **user_not_found** error. I tried some of the suggested solutions like; destroying & recreating docker containers, naming username and password different than "admin" and "password" etc but none of them worked. Anyone who have solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who encounter this problem, my issue was:

```
proxy_set_header content-type "application/json";
```

line in **nginx.conf** file since **Keycloak** uses **"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"** content-type header most of its requests. Do not convert it to the **"application/x-www-form-urlencoded**" since you also need **"application/json"** header time to time. Just remove that line from configuration file and it should be fine.

Happy coding.